# error("some string") only shows error, not error + string

Tags: c++, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm learning c++ through Stroustrup's PP&P Using C++ and I've got to the chapter five which says: *"In fact, in std_lib_fa cilities.h we supply an error() function that by default terminates the program with a system error message plus the string we passed as an argument to error()."*

Here is my code:

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h";

class Neg_sqrt{};

void sqr (double a, double b, double c)
{
    if ((b*b - 4*a*c) < 0)
        throw Neg_sqrt();

    double x1 = 0, x2 = 0;

    x1 = (-b + sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/(2*a);
    x2 = (-b - sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/(2*a);

    cout << "Roots of given equation are\n" << x1 << " and " << x2 << endl;
}

int main()
try
{
    double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    cout << "Enter floating point parameters of quadratic equation: a, b and c\n";
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    sqr(a,b,c);
}

catch (Neg_sqrt)
{
    error("Sqrt of negative value is not defined!");
}
```

Error() just terminates the program it doesn't show the string sent to it. Why is this? Also, that #include "std_lib_facilities.h" can be found here: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h

Comment: The relevant function in the library used appears to be:`inline void error(const string& s)
{
 throw runtime_error(s);
}`

Comment: Well you throw from the `catch` block in main, but you never catch that exception thrown by `error(...)`. The program simply terminates and is not required to print anything.

Comment: So my error message is not supposed to be shown anywhere? I completely misunderstood that part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `error(const std::string&)` throws an exception. An exception either get's caught somewhere, or it will terminate the program. In your case, the `std::runtime_error` thrown in `error("...")` doesn't get caught. Hence, the program simply terminates (it is not required to print anything once this happens, though most operation systems print a message something along the lines of "Program exited after call to std::terminate`).

What you should do instead (if you don't actually want to throw a different exception that may be caught at a higher level), is just printing the error:

```
[...]
catch ( Neq_sqrt )
{
   std::cerr << "Sqrt of negative value is not defined!\n";
}
```